# Issue to close an overlay Phoenix Theme Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, button, portfolio

I'm using the Wordpress theme Phoenix for my portfolio but i'm having an issue with the portfolio section. Each project is open in an overlay and i can't seem to find the reason why there is no link on the cross made to close it.

https://maurugeonyannick.com/Portfolio_V2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using z-indexes and that's messing up some of your layering.
I would place a z-index of 10 to your `.overlaytop` class. That will fix your issue.

As it currently stands, your `.overlaytop` element is buried underneath your `.container` element having a z-index of 2, then within your `.container` you have your main heading with a z-index of 3, etc.

Using chrome's dev tools, adding the z-index of 10 to 
   `<div class="col-md-12 overlaytop" />`
addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I had a negative margin on the overlaytop class aswell. I knew it was something like this but i couldn't find the issue :)

```
.overlay .overlaytop {/*margin-bottom:-30px*/ z-index:10;}
```

Solved my issue.

You're the best!